# How to determine if phone was rotated Clockwise or CounterClockwise using only accelerometer

Tags: c#, windows, mobile, uwp

I have a windows 10 phone (Lumia 640) which has an accelerometer but not a gyroscope.

The Accelerometer.ReadingChanged event gives me the current values in the X, Y and Z axes.

My question is it possible to know whether the phone was rotated clockwise or counterclockwise (about the Z axis) for a given reading.

If I keep track of the previous reading, then there are still two possibilities of reaching from previous reading to current reading - CW and CCW.

Comment: Have you considered keeping track of the previous *two* readings? Assuming any kind of reasonable polling interval, you should be able to figure it out from three data points

Comment: I am a bit confused here. Say the previous two readings are **A** (12 o'clock) and **B** (2 o'clock) and the latest reading is **C** (10 o'clock). How will I calculate whether B to C was traversed in clockwise or counter clockwise manner?

Comment: It depends on your polling interval, but if you are anywhere in the 100ms range then I don't think anyone could pull off that reversal. Basically, the whole answer to your question is "poll fast enough that the user couldn't have switched without you detecting it"

Comment: What I meant to say that how to detect the switch. You are right if I poll fast enough I can get the smallest changes. But consider the scenario where points A and B are 1 degree apart and B and C are 2 degrees apart. How will I know that the user has stopped rotating clockwise and is now rotating in counter clockwise direction?

Comment: Its not the increment that matters, its the *sign*. So if A > B indicates a clockwise rotation, then if C < B you know the user is now going counter clockwise. You'll have to experiment to determine which sign means which rotation.

Comment: This approach does not work when the points A and B are on either side of the zero degree line. Say A is 359 degrees and B is 1 degree, even though the movement from A to B is clockwise, it will be calculated as counter clockwise since B < A.

Comment: Sure. That's part of the reason I suggest keeping the last *two* readings, because you should see something like 358, 359, 1; which indicates a fairly obvious direction. Even just 359 to 1 you know the direction, you just have to have a bit more logic as you indicated.